# Getting an item from an Amazon DynamoDB table into a Lambda function intent node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a table on Amazon DynamoDB called `users` with 2 items, `userID` and `userName`. Below is the code for my simple Lambda function. I have created an intent called `userNameIntent` where I want to be able to read the item `userName` from my table. So I want Alexa to respond with "Your username is " and then the `userName` from the table. Sorry for the newbie question, pretty new to coding and I can't seem to find a simple solution. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk'); 
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var DOC = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-1'});

var params = {
    TableName: 'users',
    Key: { 
        "userID": "00001"
    }
};

const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.response.speak('Welcome');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },

'userNameIntent': function () {
    this.response.speak('Your username is ');
    this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
};

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
    
    dynamodb.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err){
            callback ("error", null);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: It looks like you have the code to get the item already. It's in the `data` object in the line `callback(null, data);` You just need to do something with it there.

Answer (score 0):

You are close but a few things:

1) the intent handler must process the response by passing the intent details (ie. slot values) to the DynamoDB query that will fetch the user info

2) the intent handler cannot return a response until the DynamoDB query is complete (i.e you must only set the response from the DynamoDB callback)

Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50203485/63074) to a very similar question.